# Firefox-add-on js issue

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am coding a Web Extension. It opens up as a popup when clicked that user can interact with. Popup displays HTML and CSS correctly, but fails to execute JS.

Here the code of my manifest.json file:

`{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "To-Do List",
    "description": "Keep track of your tasks easily.",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128":"icon.png"},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/"],
        "js": ["app.js"]
    }

    ],
    "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}`

**All the files are in same directory!**

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sanjeev. Can you open your dev console (F12) and check the debugger tab. Does your script appear in that list?

Comment: No, I cannot see it there! It says 'no sources'.